# Confusion about the optimum of some (simple?) LP (min $x+y$ on square)

Tags: proof-verification, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

**Minimize** $x + y$  with the constraints

1. $a x + y \leq 4$
2. $1 \leq x \leq 3$
3. $1 \leq y \leq 3$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, the first step is to determine the possible values for $a$. I simply drew the constraints in an xy-plane and found $a \leq 3$. Otherwise (i.e. for $a > 3$), the constraint-set would be empty.

Okay, now (i.e. for $a \leq 3$) the minimum has to be $2$ at the position $(x,y)=(1,1)$, since it's the smalled value possible w.r.t. the above constraints.

But this seems way too simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a proof rather than visualization helps.

If $a> 3$, suppose the feasible set is non-empty, then $x, y >0$, then we have $$a \le \frac{4-y}{x}\le \frac{4-1}{1}=3$$

which is a contradiction.

Hence for the feasible set to be non-empty, we have have $a \le 3$.

If $a \le 3$, at $(1,1)$, $ax+y=a+1 \le 4,$ hence $(1,1)$ is a feasible point.

Hence the optimal value is $2$ when $a \le 3$ and doesn't exist otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But just to be clear: Is the full proof really that short?

Comment: For any other feasible point, $x+y>2$. hmm... anything things else that is not clear?